# Illustrator center-point issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I try to select an object to move, I'm getting the "rotation" selection instead...until I zoom in 75%...I can now finally select the center point to move the object. This is a big pain, is there a way to increase the center point or sensitivity so I'm not having to zoom in so close?

Comment: Seems this may be an issue with your input device.

Comment: I have this problem as well.